# TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined - React Native Navigation issue

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-context

I am having an issue in react native, it is my first time using useContext and I am having issues with what I believe the Tab Navigator. I am getting this error message TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined when I click on on the Login button. Below is all the different code.

**AppNav.js**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { AuthContext } from '../context/AuthContext';
import { View, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import AuthStack from './AuthStack';
import AppStack from './AppStack';


const AppNav = () => {

    const {isLoading, userToken} = useContext(AuthContext)

    if (isLoading) {

      return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <ActivityIndicator size={'large'}/>
        </View>
      )
    }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {userToken !== null ? <AppStack /> : <AuthStack />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

export default AppNav
```

**AppStack.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import Tabs from "../components/Tabs";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const AppStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Tabs"
        component={Tabs}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default AppStack;
```

**AuthStack.js**

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack'
import Login from "../screens/Login";
import Register from "../screens/Register";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const AuthStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen
    name="Login"
    component={Login}
    options={{ headerShown: false }}
  />
  <Stack.Screen
    name="Register"
    component={Register}
    options={{ headerShown: false }}
  />
  </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

export default AuthStack
```

**Tabs.js**

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import Home from "../screens/Home";
import Rewards from "../screens/Rewards";
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from "react-native";
import { FontAwesome, FontAwesome5 } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import Profile from "../screens/Profile";
import ScanCode from "../screens/ScanCode";
import QRCodeScan from "../screens/QRCodeScan";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function Tabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarShowLabel: false,
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarStyle: {
          position: "absolute",
          bottom: 25,
          left: 20,
          right: 20,
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: "white",
          borderRadius: 15,
          height: 70,
          ...styles.shadow,
        },
      }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{
       tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
        <View style={styles.tabIconView}>
          <FontAwesome name="home" size={focused ? 25 : 23} color={focused ? '#5a2e8a' : '#B3B3B3'} />
          <Text style={{fontSize: 12, color: focused ? '#5a2e8a' : '#B3B3B3'}}>HOME</Text>
        </View>
       )
      }}/>
      <Tab.Screen name="ScanCode" component={ScanCode} options={{
       tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
        <View style={styles.tabIconView}>
          <FontAwesome name="qrcode" size={focused ? 25 : 23} color={focused ? '#5a2e8a' : '#B3B3B3'} />
          <Text style={{fontSize: 12, color: focused ? '#5a2e8a' : '#B3B3B3'}}>SCAN</Text>
        </View>
       )
      }}
      
      />
          <Tab.Screen name="QRCodeScan" component={QRCodeScan} options={{
       tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
        <View style={styles.tabIconView}>
          <FontAwesome name="barcode" size={focused ? 25 : 23} color={focused ? '#5a2e8a' : '#B3B3B3'} />
          <Text style={{fontSize: 12, color: focused ? '#5a2e8a' : '#B3B3B3'}}>QR Scanner</Text>
        </View>
       )
      }}
      
      />
      <Tab.Screen name="Rewards" component={Rewards} options={{
       tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
        <View style={styles.tabIconView}>
          <FontAwesome5 name="medal" size={focused ? 25 : 23} color={focused ? '#5a2e8a' : '#B3B3B3'} />
          <Text style={{fontSize: 12, color: focused ? '#5a2e8a' : '#B3B3B3'}}>REWARDS</Text>
        </View>
       )
      }}
      
      />
      <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} options={{
       tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
        <View style={styles.tabIconView}>
          <FontAwesome name="user" size={focused ? 25 : 23} color={focused ? '#5a2e8a' : '#B3B3B3'} />
          <Text style={{fontSize: 12, color: focused ? '#5a2e8a' : '#B3B3B3'}}>PROFILE</Text>
        </View>
       )
      }}
      
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

export default Tabs;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  shadow: {
    shadowColor: "#75F5DF0",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 10,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 3.5,
    elevation: 5,
  },
  tabIconView: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    top: 15,
  }
});
```

**Login.js**

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, SafeAreaView, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions, KeyboardAvoidingView } from "react-native";
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext } from "react";
import { auth } from "../firebase";
import { AuthContext } from "../context/AuthContext";

export const height = Dimensions.get('screen').height;
export const width = Dimensions.get('screen').width;

const Login = ({navigation}) => {


    function navigateToRegister() {
        navigation.replace('Register')
    }

    const {login} = useContext(AuthContext);


  return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <Image source={require("../images/logo.png")} style={styles.logo} />
        <Text style={styles.welcomeText}>BlaqCat Rewards</Text>
        <View style={styles.cardContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Login</Text>
        
        <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <TextInput placeholder="Email" style={styles.inputBox} autoCapitalize="none" inputMode="email" value={email} onChangeText={text => setEmail(text)}/>
            <TextInput placeholder="Password" style={styles.inputBox} value={password} onChangeText={text => setPassword(text)}/>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {login()}}>
                <View style={styles.loginButton}>
                    <Text style={styles.loginButtonText}>Login</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={navigateToRegister}>
                <View style={styles.registerButton}>
                    <Text style={styles.registerButtonText}>Register</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default Login;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#8041C3",
  },
  logo: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
  },
  welcomeText: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 190,
    right: 35,
    fontSize: width < 428 ? 24 : 28,
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  inputContainer: {
    marginTop: 12,
    width: '100%',
    padding: 10,
    flex: 1,
  },

  inputBox: {
    padding: 12,
    borderColor: 'purple',
    borderWidth: 1,
    margin: 6,
    borderRadius: 6,
  },
  loginButton: {
    marginTop: 20,
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#5a2e8a',
    padding: 16,
    width: width / 1.8,
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  loginButtonText: {
    color: 'white',
  },
  registerButton: {
    marginTop: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    padding: 16,
    width: width / 1.8,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#5a2e8a',
  },
  registerButtonText: {
    color: '#5a2e8a',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 26,
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  cardContainer: {
    marginTop: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#F8F5FB',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: width / 1.15,
    padding: 12,
    height: height / 2.5,
    borderRadius: 20,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 8,
    shadowOffset: {width: 2, height: 2},
  },

});
```

**AuthContext.js**

```
import React, {createContext, useState} from 'react'

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
    const [userToken, setUserToken] = useState(null)

    const login = () => {
        setUserToken('idjsa')
        setIsLoading(false)
    }

    const logout = () => {
        setUserToken(null)
        setIsLoading(false);
    }

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{login, logout, isLoading, userToken}}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

**Home.js**

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Dimensions,
  SafeAreaView,
  Image,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity
} from "react-native";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { auth, db } from "../firebase";
import { doc, onSnapshot, updateDoc, increment } from "firebase/firestore";
import CardView from "../components/CardView";
import { FontAwesome5 } from "@expo/vector-icons";

export const height = Dimensions.get("screen").height;
export const width = Dimensions.get("screen").width;

const Home = () => {
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState([])
  const currentUser = auth.currentUser?.uid;

  useEffect(() => {

    const userInfoRef = doc(db, "users", currentUser);
    const subscriber = onSnapshot(userInfoRef, (doc) => {
      const currentUserInfo = []
      currentUserInfo.push({...doc.data()})
      setUserInfo(currentUserInfo)
    })
    return () => subscriber();
  }, []);

  const addPoint = async () => {
    const docRef = doc(db, "users", currentUser);
    await updateDoc(docRef, {
      points: increment(100)
    })
    console.log("Point Added")
  }

  // const sendToRewards = () => {
  //   navigation.navigate("Rewards")
  // }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.mainContainer}>
      <Image source={require("../images/logo.png")} style={styles.logo} />
      <Text style={styles.logoText}>BlaqCat Rewards</Text>
    <CardView>
      <View style={{borderBottomWidth: 2, borderColor: '#CCC', padding: 6, width: '60%' }}>
      <Text style={{fontSize: 18, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Welcome {userInfo.map((item) => item.firstname)} !</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 30, backgroundColor: '#64329A', padding: 8, borderRadius: 20, marginBottom: 10}}>
        <Text style={{color: 'white', fontSize: 18}}>Account Summary</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.rewardsContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.points}>Hookah points </Text>
        <View style={{alignItems: 'center', borderColor: '#8041C3', width: 60, padding: 6, backgroundColor: '#8041C3', borderRadius: 6}}>
        <FontAwesome5 name="medal" size={25} color={'white'}/>
        <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>{userInfo.map((item) => item.points)}</Text>
        </View>  
      </View>
      <View style={styles.rewardsContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.points}>Level</Text>
        <View style={{alignItems: 'center', borderColor: '#8041C3', width: 60, padding: 6, backgroundColor: '#8041C3', borderRadius: 6}}>
        <FontAwesome5 name="trophy" size={25} color={'white'}/>
        <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>1</Text>
        </View>
        </View>
        <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={addPoint}>
        <View style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Add Point</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>      
    </CardView>
    {/* <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={sendToRewards}>
        <View style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Spend Points</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      </View> */}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default Home;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#8041C3",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  logo: {
    width: 175,
    height: 150,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  button: {
    marginTop: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    padding: 16,
    width: width / 3,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#5a2e8a',
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: "#5a2e8a",
  },
  points: {
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  rewardsContainer: {
    marginTop: 2,
    flexDirection: 'row', 
    alignItems: 'center', 
    justifyContent: 'space-between', 
    padding: 6
  },
  logoText: {
    color: 'white',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 150,
    right: 115,
    fontSize: 18
  },
});
```

Please help!!

I have tried looking up topics here and also watched videos on YouTube. I believe the issue is going to be an easy fix, but can't seem to find an answer anywhere.

Comment: Click on the "Login" button triggers a function in `AuthContext`. Can you update this piece of code as well?

Comment: My apologies for not including that information. I have updated the post with the code and file AuthContext.js

Comment: Is there any stacktrace? Looking at the code I do not see any issue. Login button updates  the context's `userToken` which rerenders the App to `AppStack`, opening Tabs/Home component...

Comment: AppStack is the one having issues rendering.. I have tried rendering just the AppStack in the **AppNav.js** file and still get the same error. For testing purposes I also tried in AppNav doing {userToken !== null ? null : <AuthStack />} and it does display a blank page, so it must be the Tab navigation that is messing up. As for the stacktrace `This error is located at:
    in Home (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by BottomTabView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Screen)`

Comment: Then can you please add Home component's code? The issue seems to be in there. And Context usage seems to be correct

Comment: Just updated the post with Home.js

Comment: I do not see anywhere that you make the firebase `auth`, so my best guess is that in the Home view `const currentUser = auth.currentUser?.uid;` is either null or undefined, and then the queries in the `users` store cannot be retrieved generating the issue?

Comment: @Jhilton You were 100% right! It was the Firebase stuff that were causing the issues. Once I implemented the login function into the AuthContext.js file the issue was resolved. Thank you!!